# Can't install apertium language packages from source - make command shows errors

Tags: bash, makefile, apertium

I am trying to install apertium-eng-ita package from source (available at https://github.com/apertium/apertium-eng-ita). The system is debian 11 (i tried also on fresh ubuntu, get the same error). So i downloaded all the files into my /root directory (/root/eng-ita contents all the files from provided link) and run:

> ./autogen.sh

This generated all the necessary files inside the "eng-ita" folder, including "Makefile". But then i run:

> make

and see errors like:

> apertium-validate-dictionary apertium-eng-ita.eng-ita.dix /bin/bash:
> apertium-validate-dictionary: command not found make: ***
> [Makefile:769: eng-ita.autobil.bin] Error 127

I began googling (for example, here is some info - https://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Installation_troubleshooting) this 127 error and found some information about PATH, but where i can put this PATH to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're installing from source, you should first add the apt source and install apertium-all-dev which will give you `make` etc. Cf. https://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Prerequisites_for_Debian you should

```
curl -sS https://apertium.projectjj.com/apt/install-nightly.sh | sudo bash

sudo apt-get -f install locales build-essential automake subversion git pkg-config \
                        gawk libtool apertium-all-dev
```

(But you don't need to install from source if you just want to use the pair and not develop for it. There are nightly debian packages of the latest git commit; after running the first command you can get that package with `sudo apt install apertium-eng-ita`)

Comment: This is a working solution, thanks. But maybe you have some thoughts about putting PATH in the right place? Anyway, i will mark this comment as a solution, bacuse now i have eng-ita package installed

Comment: So it was fine on fresh Ubuntu, but language package installation fails on Debian 11: _The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apertium-eng-ita : Depends: apertium (>= 3.8.0) but 3.7.1-1 is to be installed
Depends: apertium-lex-tools (>= 0.3.0) but 0.2.7-1 is to be installed_ And i can't update apertium to newer version - it shows me, that the version is already up-to-date...

Comment: What does `uname -a` give?